# How to save response string from web service into a xml file locally in c#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, model-view-controller

I'm calling to a web service that has .ashx extension and getting string as a response.Now I am trying to save it in a xml file. project execute correctly but it does not save in xml file.

```
 public void savexmlFile()
        {
            string wbserviceUrl = "https://someurl.ashx";
            WebClient clientOne = new WebClient();
            string result = clientOne.DownloadString(wbserviceUrl);

            XmlDocument cruisexmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            cruisexmlDocument.LoadXml(result);
            cruisexmlDocument.Save("D:/brian office projects/Cruise/Cruise/XmlFiles/Cruisedata/cruiseproduts.xml");
        }
```

how can I do that.

this is the result when we enter url directly in brower.

```
<CruiseData CreationDate="2015-11-11T00:00:03.9702000+00:00">
<CruiseProduct>
<ID>3706</ID>
<Name>MS SUNRISE SERMIRAMIS COLLECTION</Name>
<Description>
<p>Our Selected Nile Cruise <b>MS Sunrise Semiramis</b> <b>Collection Nile Cruise</b> the world’s greatest open air museum, to Aswan. Be enchanted by the fascinating landscape and rich cultural heritage. On our cruiser you will surely experience one of your most memorable vacations.<br><br><b>The Nile is the world's longest river</b> and a luxury cruise on an elegant ship is the most relaxing way to discover the cultural landmarks and archaeological sites of Egypt. Retrace the routes followed by Egypt's pharaohs from Luxor and wonder at the views over Lake Nasser from Aswan's High Dam.<br><b><br>We offer a choice of luxury Nile cruises</b> with various itineraries along the Nile and across Lake Nasser, and are delighted to feature a small selection of the most intimate, elegant and sophisticated vessels. Normal cruise itineraries include embarkation at Luxor, a cruise to Aswan, then disembarkation in Luxor, although some cruises end in Aswan, or can be booked from Aswan. For cruises ending or starting in Aswan, we can easily book travel between Aswan and Luxor.<br><br><b>Nile cruise holidays are an exceptional</b> way to visit some of Egypt’s most famed and most captivating sights. The famed Valley of the Kings contains more than sixty tombs, chambers and halls: the most famous, Tutankhamen, contains a tomb with the mummy in situ, and the Valley of the Queens offers interesting insights into the Egyptian way of life as Queens and royal children were buried in separate valleys. One of the most magnificent monuments is the Temple of Queen Hatshepsut: dedicated to Egypt’s greatest female pharaoh. The Colossi of Memnon which is two huge stone sentinels overlooking the Nile, requires special mention, as does the Temple of Luxor, and the Temple of Karnack with its daily Sound and Light Show.<br><br><b>With Combo Holidays River Nile cruises</b> covering the routes between Luxor and Aswan; the cruise itineraries feature some fantastic stops along the way. At Edfu there’s a very well preserved temple dedicated to Horus - the second largest temple in Egypt. The Aswan High Dam built during the 1960’s to stem annual floods and provide hydroelectricity, boasts good views over Lake Nasser, and the two islands of the Nile offer contrasting attractions; Kitchener's Island boasts the exotic Botanical Gardens and Elephantine Island is home to the Temple of Khnum with its ram mummies on view at the museum.<br><br><b>MS Sunrise Semiramis</b> will take you on a cruise from Luxor, the world’s greatest open air museum, to Aswan. Be enchanted by the fascinating landscape and rich cultural heritage. On our cruiser you will surely experience one of your most memorable vacations.<br><br><b>64 Standard Cabins</b> are waiting to welcome you. All cabins offer an amazing view on the Nile. The finest facilities can be
```

Comment: 1) Check to make sure the path is correct and you have write permission to the directory (and pre-existing file, if present.) 2) Are you sure the XML string actually has any contents?

Comment: yes I'm sure. because I can get string in to datatable. why I am doing this is web service take lot time to load(response)

Answer (score 0):

String, u downloaded from service has a xml format? If not, cruisexmlDocument.LoadXml(result); doesn't take effect, it just loads in memory XML string.

Answer (score 0):

Just download your content read it as string, and write it. You don't need to handle it as XML excplicitly, unless you need to do some verification that it is a valid XML in some way. Other than that, just download it and write it. Make sure you have permissions to write to your path.

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = httpClient.GetAsync("your url").Result;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\yourxml.xml", result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```